# Authentication failed while calling WCF service from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-security

Platform: VS 2008, .NET 3.5, C#, Oracle 11g

I've created a WCF service which takes some data elements and then inserts them into a database table and returns an integer. I've also created a small ASP.NET web app to test that service. The test web app only has a page with the fields and a button, clicking that button actually calls the web service to insert the data and return a integer value.

The steps I took:

- Build the WCF service
- Publish the WCF Service
- Generate the proxy class (.cs) and app.config using svcutil
- Build the test asp.net app and add the proxy class and config settings as generated on the above step.
- Ruin the test app

It works fine when I deploy both the WCF and the test web app on my computer - Windows XP, IIS 5.1. But, whenever I'm trying to deploy them on a remote server it doesn't work. When I'm trying to consume the service (deployed on remote server - Windows 2003 server, IIS 6) I'm getting the following error:

> The request for security token could not be satisfied because
>   authentication failed.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The request for
>   security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.

Following are the .config files content:

**wcf section of the Web.Config of calling ASP.NET web app (Consumer):**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyWCFService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://57.23.85.28:8001/MyWCFService/MyWCFService.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyWCFService"
      contract="IMyWCFService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyWCFService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Web.Config of the WCF:**

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DSMyWCF" connectionString="Data Source=XXX;User id=XXX;Password=XXX;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyWCFService.MyWCFServiceBehavior"
        name="MyWCFService.MyWCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyWCFService.IMyWCFService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFService/MyWCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyWCFService.MyWCFServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information,
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes,
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be related with security configuration of wcf service, to be specific, Windows credential type requires valid domain username and password information.

Try providing the following attributes on clientside;

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "UserName ";
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "Password ";
proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "Domain ";
```